# How to check connection to mongodb is active?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

What method should I call on `Mongo::Client` object to check that connection to the database server is active?

```
require 'mongo'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = '27017'

client = Mongo::Client.new("mongodb://#{host}:#{port}")
```

Comment: Define 'valid'?  It will raise an error if it was unable to connect

Comment: I tried just now (mongo 2.2.x) and it doesn't raise an error (seems like it retries in the background or something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mtj suggested, to check if connection is valid/active I am trying to get the list of databases as below:

```
require 'mongo'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = '27017'

begin
  client = Mongo::Client.new("mongodb://#{host}:#{port}")
  client.database_names
rescue Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized, Mongo::Error => e
  info_string  = "Error #{e.class}: #{e.message}"
  puts info_string
end
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoClient in various languages is implemented as a "lazy stub", so that you will not get an immediate error, if the connection is not possible. Instead, you get the error when a concrete query goes over the line.

As far as I know, the only way to be sure that an *actual* connection takes place is, to query some data from the server. For example, in our project, we simply read the list of databases upon initialization.

Note: as the query results also may be lazy stubs, make sure to actually *read* the result in your client ;-)